# How to get peer nodes information from bitcoin CLI?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, bitcoincore-gui

I saw a feature called *Node Window* in the bitcoin GUI environment, that shows information about peer nodes, like User-Agent, Received (Data), Sent (Data), Ip, etc.

How do I can get such information from the bitcoin core full node CLI environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getpeerinfo` command returns the same data.